# How to rotatate card with angle on swap?

Tags: android, rotation, android-cardview

I am using Cardstackview library and I want to rotate card while swiping left and right.

```java
manager.setSwipeThreshold(0.3f);
manager.setMaxDegree(190);
manager.setDirections(Direction.HORIZONTAL);
manager.setCanScrollHorizontal(true);
manager.setCanScrollVertical(false);

binding.cardStackView.setLayoutManager(manager);
cardStackAdapter = new CardStackAdapter(listCard, getActivity());
binding.cardStackView.setAdapter(cardStackAdapter);
```

Here is XML code :

```xml
<com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackView
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/card_stack_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackView>
```

Please help me. Rotation from an angle is not working, I am using this library:

> https://github.com/yuyakaido/CardStackView#swipe-thresh

I would appreciate every answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the sample of the library, they are using padding instead of margin:

```
<com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackView
    android:id="@+id/card_stack_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/button_container"
    android:padding="4dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false">
</com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackView>
```

Thus, you could try that (change margin to padding and add clipToPadding attribute):

```
<com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackView
    android:paddingStart="5dp"
    android:paddingEnd="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:id="@+id/card_stack_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackView>
```

Comment: Do you have erros in the log?

Comment: I proposed a new solution (I don't know if you have a notification when I edit it)